# How to solve this diff equation in matlab?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The ODE

\begin{cases}
y'' − Cxy = g(x),\\
y(2) = 1,\\
y'(2) = 0, 
\end{cases}

where

$$
g(x) =
\begin{cases}
  −1 & 2 \leq x \leq 3, \\
−1/3 & 3 \leq x \leq 5,
\end{cases}
$$

should get solved for for $C=0.8$, $1$, and $2$ at the interval $2 \leq x \leq 5$.

I must write a MATLAB program that performs the calculation and draws the $3$ solution curves in the same graph.

I should rewrite the problem as a system of first order:

$
u_1 = y,\\
u_2 = y',\\
u_2' = y''.
$

Hence

$
u_2'-Cxu_1=g(x),\\
u_1(2)=1.
u_2(0)=2.
$

How do I continue?

### Update

I used this function file in matlab

```
function f=func(x,u)
global C;
if x<3
g=-1;
else
g=-x/3;
end
f=[u(2)
C*x*u(1)+g];
```

then I run this program

```
>> global C;
>> for C=[0.05 0.1 0.2]
[X, U]=ode45(@func,[2 5],[1;0]);
plot(X,U(:,1)); hold on
end
```

and I get this graph, is it correct?
[image]

Comment: Have you written any code yet?  Especially since this is a homework question, it is good to demonstrate that you've tried _something_ before you ask for help.

Comment: @RichieCotton thank you for the comment. I've now made an extensive effort and nearly solved the entire problem if you want to have a look and comment my code that I tried to write. I'm not sure whether my solution is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [ode45, ode23](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode23.html) in matlab. These are commands to solve differential equations numerically. try help in matlab for more information about these commands